# Outputting each element of a string list on its own line as a string - sml

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I'm new to SML and find it frustrating to say the least.

I using a datatype, which I'll call entry

```
datatype entry =
    File of string
  | Directory of string * contents
withtype contents = entry list
```

to help me create a composite pattern of a file directory like so

```
val files =
  Directory("d1",
    [ File "f1",
      Directory("d2",
        [ File "f2",
          Directory("d3",[File "f3"])
        ]),
      File "f4",
      Directory("d3",[File "f5"])
    ]);
```

I want to create mutually recursive functions (something I just learned about) that will print each entry in files on its own line. Essentially having the output as this:

> ```
> d1
> f1
> ...
> f5
> ```

I have tried this:

```
fun print_entries (File s) = [s] (* I've even tried s^"\n" but that only gets me "f#\n" for each file *)
|   print_entries (Directory(s, contents)) = s::(print_contents contents)
and
print_contents nil = nil
|   print_contents (e::es) = print_entries e @ (print_contents es)
```

but it only outputs a list of the entries. Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `print_entries`/`print_contents` function currently produces a list, which can easily be printed:

```
fun print_line s = (print s; print "\n")

List.app print_line (print_entries files)
```

Otherwise, you could redefine it to print the files directly:

```
fun print_entries (File s) = print_line s
|   print_entries (Directory(s, contents)) = (print_line s; print_contents contents)
and print_contents [] = ()
|   print_contents (e::es) = (print_entries e; print_contents es)
```

The structure is the same, but instead of using `::` and `@` to recursively construct a list, you use imperative commands (`print`) and sequencing (`;`).

A minor note: there is no need to use `withtype` in the definition of `entry`:

```
datatype entry =
  File of string
| Directory of string * entry list
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! Sorry, I've juggling a few other assignments alongside this one.

Answer (score 1):

Given your entry type,

```
datatype entry = File of string | Directory of string * entry list
```

you can either generate a list of file/directory names by mutual recursion,

```
fun names (File name) = [name]
  | names (Directory (name, entries)) = name :: names_entries entries

and names_entries [] = []
  | names_entries (entry :: entries) = names entry @ names_entries entries
```

Or you can resort to handle the list `entries` using `List.map`:

```
fun names (File name) = [name]
  | names (Directory (name, entries)) =
      name :: List.concat (List.map names entries))
```

Since each call to `names <entry>` performed by `List.map` produces a list of names, `List.map names entries` produces a list of *lists of* names. Flattening that back into a single list of names is done with `List.concat`.

This is sort of like mutual recursion, but the mutual dependency between `entry` and `entry list` is embedded in the `names` function passed to `List.map` and the list recursion is handled by `List.map` alone.

---

You can also get a list of names by folding over the file entry:

```
fun cata f acc entry =
    case entry of
         File name => f (entry, acc)
       | Directory (name, entries) =>
           let val acc' = f (entry, acc) in
             foldl (fn (entry, acc'') => cata f acc'' entry) acc'
           end

fun name (File name) = name
  | name (Directory (name, _)) = name

val names =
  rev o cata (fn (entry, names) => name entry :: names) []
```

This function is useful for other things, e.g. counting the number of files and directories recursively:

```
fun isFile (File _) = true
  | isFile (Directory _) = false

fun isDirectory (Directory _) = true
  | isDirectory (File _) = false

val countFilesDirectories =
  let fun counter (entry, (numFiles, numDirs)) =
    if isFile entry then (numFiles+1, numDirs) else
    if isDirectory entry then (numFiles, numDirs+1) else
    (numFiles, numDirs)
  in cata counter (0,0) end
```

Or even print the file and directory names recursively:

```
val printEntries =
  cata (fn (entry, ()) => print (name entry ^ "\n")) ()
```